# Get items without related model

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

Hi i'm racking my brain out at this problem for some time and cant seem to find any solution without using custom function

I have two models

```
Inventory   --hasOne-->   Order
Order     --belongsTo-->  Inventory
```

And i want to list Inventory items without related Orders is there any way to do this with filter JSON?

Thanks for any advices :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to call this:

`http://localhost:3000/api/Inventory?filter={"where": {"orderId": null}}`

The disadvantage of this is that you have to make sure that the field is there and it's empty (value is set to `null`) if the property is not set you will have to build your own query.

To pre-set the null value in the Inventory model, you can use "before save" hook and check if the `orderId` is set, then set it to null if not.

Otherwise, you can just call a custom function, although I recommend using the default ones as long as possible.

Comment: kind knew about null method but didn't want to clutter model with unused properties. Thanks nevertheless :P